# WooCommerce PayPal Plugin Not Compatible with Subscriptions?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, paypal, woocommerce-subscriptions

Has anyone had issues with PayPal and woocommerce subscriptions?
The PayPal plugin dose not seem to save the payment method (paypal vault), automatically capture the payment and payments will be set to on hold and then fail without manual authorization. Rebelling won't work because paypal vault doesn't seen to save the payment method from the customer.

Everything seems to be set up correctly and there is no errors in the logs.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-paypal-payments/#multiple-and-pre-existing-subscriptions) is the answer to the question.

You can't use the same PayPal business account for subscription on multiple website.